# Embedding graphs in my page

Tags: neo4j

the Neo4j server comes with a Web interface for quick queries.  is it possible for me to issue an ajax call from my web page to hand the server a query and load a local div with the resulting graph?

I've not found examples of how to do this and have spent more than a reasonable amount of time trying to decypher their code for how it's done

Answer (score 0):

Yes I wrote a demo that does that:

see: http://jexp.github.io/cy2neo

It currently doesn't support auth so you have to disable auth, if you want to add it I'd be happy about a pull request.

code to access neo4j via jquery: https://github.com/jexp/cy2neo/blob/master/scripts/neo.js
repository: http://github.com/jexp/cy2neo

Comment: ok, I see.  this is a re-implementation of the graphs.  it doesn't use the graphs that the Neo server produces.  your project's graphs don't have any of the functionality that's available in the graphs that the Neo server provides.  what I was hoping for is that I could just embed their graphs into my pages

Comment: We had plans for that, but those got delayed / distracted. The closest to the original Neo4j visualization is part of the grapgist project: github.com/neo4j-contrib/graphgist

Comment: @MichaelHunger, yes, I had come across the gists already... I need to install python but they look cool.  still, I wish someone had figured out how to just embed neo server's own pages into a page.  I don't know enough Angular (yet) to figure it out

Comment: Michael, I followed the instructions in your script (here: https://gist.github.com/jexp/70296ce410ff431ddbef) and I'm now running graphgist locally, however, the last line:

open http://localhost:8000/?http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000%2Fgists%2Fmy-graph-use-case.adoc
causes my browser to display an error: `Not Found`, and trying to open this link: `http://localhost:8000/gists/my-graph-use-case.adoc` causes my browser to download a file for which I don't have an associated application.

I must be close but what am I missing?